# How to plot real time line graph

Tags: android, achartengine, linegraph, android-graphview

I am creating sound meter app in android I want to show values in line graph on real time anyone please tell me how I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

For time operations please see android.text.format.Time
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Time.html

This is official sample code from there:

```
Time time = new Time();
time.set(4, 10, 2007);  // set the date to Nov 4, 2007, 12am
time.normalize(false);       // this sets isDst = 1
time.monthDay += 1;     // changes the date to Nov 5, 2007, 12am
millis = time.toMillis(false);   // millis is Nov 4, 2007, 11pm
millis = time.toMillis(true);    // millis is Nov 5, 2007, 12am
```

Now for showing the graph there is no ready class, so you will have to draw it yourself by overriding the `Draw()` function of `View` class, or to search a library to do this, for example: http://android-graphview.org/

Answer (score 0):

When using AChartEngine, you just need to add the new values to the series and call `mChartView.repaint()` in order to have the chart refresh with the new updates.

Answer (score 0):

in onCreate(...):

```
GraphView graphView = new LineGraphView(this, "Amplitude");
graphView.setScrollable(true);
graphView.setViewPort(0, 30); // the x range you want to show without scrolling
GraphViewSeries graphSeries = new GraphViewSeries(new GraphViewDataInterface[0]);
graphView.addSeries(graphSeries);
setContentView(graphView);
//or add your graphView to the Activity's view as appropriate
```

then, as you get new values:

```
graphSeries.appendData(new GraphView.GraphViewData(xValue, yValue), true, 300); 
//where 300 is the maximum number of values to keep
```

New values will come in on the right, and the GraphView will automatically scroll to show the most recent data on the chart.